# How is Gmail Email allowing Hover effect?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I receive emails from Behave Annual inviting me to events. Came across something very weird on their newsletter. All buttons and some portions of text had CSS hover effects. On mouse hover, the color would change.

From my understanding, Gmail stripped anything added to the `<head>` portion of a HTML email document. Upon Inspect Element, I found the hover effect style to be loading from the `<head>` portion.

This is the DOM -

```
<table width="250" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin:0 auto;border-radius:4px" bgcolor="#C012C9" lang="x-cta">
<tbody
<tr>
    <td height="52" valign="middle" align="center" style="vertical-align:middle;font-size:18px;text-align:center;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif,'Work Sans';font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:.08em"><a href="http://mkto-ab090038.com/x0F0000k1j507RJ0SR5jXVG" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fffffe" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://mkto-ab090038.com/x0F0000k1j507RJ0SR5jXVG&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1475210579576000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHzAxSjelTbM4Ko3G9gP-viljOzOw"><img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/w_W_24g8lpz0y_rVlaX7m8vTQNv1CXL00edUPLYMHSwY8oEtD7ns-a-IWxZsBcjHrrFffonr-da-qa-_vITS05DwmYTE_IIv-Q7Yv_3TyoMmH8fNTqnTIKUFS0hyMCD5dcH2JQVnr6VpmkrOH5tgMTI3YeRG=s0-d-e1-ft#https://assets.bounceexchange.com/assets/uploads/users/700/38798606b59c4fe750c8af1b3c0e0461.png" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;border:0;white-space:pre-wrap;text-align:center" alt="LOOK INSIDE" class="CToWUd"></a>
    </td>
</tr>    
</tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS inside `<style>` in `<head>` is as follows

```
div.m1577254c07a8a7f6 * [lang=x-cta]:hover {
    background-color: #c7dd40!important;
}
div.m1577254c07a8a7f6 * [lang=x-cta]:hover {
    background-color: #c7dd40!important;
}
```

How are they able to acheive this?

Answer (score 4):

Google has updated support this year in email clients and now more is possible:

> Gmail & Inbox support a rich subset of CSS properties & media queries to help you ensure that your message is formatted the way you intended... 
>   standard `<style>` tags can now be included in HTML bodies, eliminating the need to use inline styles. [source](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/)

Though I haven't found this in a Google sources, it also seems that `:hover` is supported only for part of the users.
[image: CSS support by Gmail from]
Image from https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-e88cd7995cea#.upjtbzcjm

It also looks like some hack to get `:hover` working exists too: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1275-gmail-app-gmail-webmail-and-inbox-metrics